# Wildly different results in not that different conditions

Tags: machine-learning, tensorflow

First I trained the network on a cloud computer, then bought a GPU and trained it locally. [My code is the same](https://github.com/tasuki/minotaur-data), yet the results are *extremely* different. I tried training various networks and the trend is the same: on the cloud computer, it behaves "nicely", locally, validation is jumping around and it's generally a lot noisier.

I created a [jupyter notebook comparing the differences visually](https://gist.github.com/tasuki/12e7b4babf7e782d05917200efb558d8).

This is not a very well formulated question. Unfortunately I don't have access to the cloud computer anymore and can't really test this further. I'm looking for general ideas rather than definite answers. Cheers!

Comment: Annoying answer.. retune your hyper parameters. From the plots it looks like you need to regularize somehow now. Why that is, if the code is the same but the hardware different... not sure.  It might be related to the drivers and stuff that you've been working on, but if you don't know the exact configuration of the cloud machine it's probably going to be a massive pain. Since you're loading the train/test splits from files I don't think that is the issue.  I don't see that you're explicitly setting the learning rate (maybe I missed it) but perhaps the default LR has changed between versions.